# Java Decompiler shows //INTERNAL ERROR// and nothing else on two files

Tags: java, minecraft, decompiling

I'm trying to decompile the Minecraft alpha 1.0.0 jar file, and well on two files all I get is //INTERNAL ERROR//.

I've looked into this and I haven't found any fixes for my problem. Other decompilers (Procyon) just don't return an output file on the files that return //INTERNAL ERROR//. What can I do about this? Why does it say internal error?

I have no clue what the problem is or why it happens.

*Any* help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why are you even looking at a 9 year old **alpha**-version file?

Comment: It presumably says "internal error" because the author of the decompiler thought it was a problem internal to the decompiler.   But if no other decompiler can decompile the same file either, it points to a problem in the file.

Comment: You've mentioned other decompilers (Procyon), so you're aware that there is not "one Java Decompiler". Maybe Notch used an obfuscator. Maybe your decompiler isn't very good. Who knows?